# Getting rid of large ignored list

Tags: git, version-control

After a composer update, and a commit of the update, a large amount of files that were ignored have been deleted. Now, anytime I run `git status`, my WHOLE terminal (hundreds of lines) is flooded by deleted files. How can I get rid of that list?

Comment: If you see them as deleted, then they were not ignored before.

Comment: they are deleted in my local directory, not on my remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment, if `git status` marks those files as `deleted`, it means that not only they weren't ignored, but also they were committed.

If you actually want to delete those files, you just need to run

```
git commit -am "Removing files after composer update"
```

after doing this, just run `git status`, and you'll see that those files aren't listed as `deleted` anymore

Comment: this worked... what is the difference between `git add .` then `git commit -m "message"` from git commit -am `message`? To me it was the same thing, but `git add .` never added the files.

Comment: `git commit -a` will commit every modifications on files already handled by git, but ignore other files. `git add .` tells git to start to handle each files in the current directory and below

Comment: so `git add --all` would be the equivalent? I like to see what I'm adding before committing

Comment: `git commit -a` will commit changes listed by `git status`. And if you realize afterward that you don't like a commit, you can always reset it. Anyway: yes, I believe `git add --all` should work.